# Windows 7 start menu shrink or tidy

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

[Here](http://i47.tinypic.com/igepus.png) and [here](http://i46.tinypic.com/2i78pdy.png) are a pictures of my Windows 7 start menu; what a waist of space.

Can I either make it so that it by default shows "All Programs" as I don't care for "recently used" or, remove that left hand side pane if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool call [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) which will revert your Start Menu to a Windows 2000 style menu.

> Classic Shell is a collection of features that were available in older versions of Windows but were later removed. It has a customizable Start menu and Start button for Windows 7 and Windows 8, it adds a toolbar for Windows Explorer and supports a variety of smaller features.

[image]

> - Drag and drop to let you organize your applications
> - Options to show Favorites, expand Control Panel, etc
> - Shows recently used documents. The number of documents to display is customizable
> - Translated in 35 languages, including Right-to-left support for Arabic and Hebrew
> - Does not disable the original start menu in Windows. You can access it by Shift+Click on the start button
> - Right-click on an item in the menu to delete, rename, sort, or perform other tasks
> - The search box helps you find your programs without getting in the way of your keyboard shortcuts
> - Available for 32 and 64-bit operating systems
> - Has support for skins, including additional 3rd party skins
> - Fully customizable in both looks and functionality
> - Support for Microsoft’s Active Accessibility
> - Converts the “All Programs” button in the Windows menu into a cascading menu (Vista and Windows 7)
> - Implements a customizable Start button (Windows 7 and 8)
> - And last but not least – it's FREE!

Comment: Also awesome for giving you back your Start menu that is now completely missing in Win8 :)

Answer (score 1):

Would [startmenu7](http://www.startmenu7.com/screenshot.html) be an option for you?